# TouchXML to read in twitter feed for iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, touchxml

So I've managed to get the feed from twitter and am attempting to parse it...
I only require the following fields from the feed:
name, description, time_zone and created_at
I am successfully pulling out name and description.. however time_zone and created_at always are nil... The following is the code...

Anyone see why this might not be working?

```
-(void) friends_timeline_callback:(NSData *)data{

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data  encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Data from twitter: %@", string);

    NSMutableArray *res = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
    CXMLDocument *doc = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:data options:0 error:nil] autorelease]; 
    NSArray *nodes = nil; 

    //! searching for item nodes 
    nodes = [doc nodesForXPath:@"/statuses/status/user" error:nil]; 

    for (CXMLElement *node in nodes) 
    { 
        int counter; 
        Contact *contact  = [[Contact alloc] init]; 

        for (counter = 0; counter < [node childCount]; counter++) 
        { 
            //pulling out name and description only for the minute!!!
            if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] name] isEqual:@"name"]){
                contact.name = [[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue];

            }else if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] name] isEqual:@"description"]) {

                // common procedure: dictionary with keys/values from XML node 
                if ([[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] == NULL){
                    contact.nextAction = @"No description";
                }else{
                    contact.nextAction = [[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue];
                }

            }else if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] name] isEqual:@"created_at"]){

                contact.date == [[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue];

            }else if([[[node childAtIndex:counter] name] isEqual:@"time_zone"]){

                contact.status == [[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue];
                [res addObject:contact];
                [contact release];
            }
        } 
    }
    self.contactsArray = res;
    [res release];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Fiona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a mistake but why are they double equals (==), usually used for a condition check

Comment: Thanks a million.. i've been staring at that for ages and now i feel really stupid... but thanks again!!

Comment: Np, I usually do it the other way round and assign something in an if statement and wonder why its always true. Happy coding